# Django URLs aren't working

Tags: python, django

Keep getting a 404 error whenever I try and access the site.

This is my urls.py in my app called `userprofile`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'ˆ$', views.index, name = 'index')
]
```

These are my urls.py:

```
from userprofile import urls


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'ˆusers/', include('userprofile.urls')),
]
```

and this is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I don't get any errors in the console.

```
Traceback:
Not Found: /users/
[11/Jun/2017 17:17:47] "GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2036
```

and I have tried `/users/`

Comment: What url are you accessing that gives a 404?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye /users

Comment: Did you try `/users/`? And do show the traceback.

Comment: Have you restarted the development server?

Comment: @Chris yes. didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a different albeit look-alike character instead of the regex line start character:

```
ˆ
```

Instead of:

```
^
```

---

```
>>> 'ˆ' == '^'
False
```

Comment: I have no idea how I did that... Thank you it works now